# Converting PyTorch Boolean target to regression target

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

### Question

I have code that is based on [Part 2, Chapter 11](https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/tree/master/p2ch11) of *Deep Learning with PyTorch*, by Luca Pietro Giovanni Antiga, Thomas Viehmann, and Eli Stevens.  It's working just fine.  It predicts the value of a Boolean variable.  I want to convert this so that it predicts the value of a real number variable that happens to be always between 0 and 34.

There are two parts that I don't know how to convert.  First, [this part](https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/blob/d6c0210143daa133bbdeddaffc8993b1e17b5174/p2ch11/dsets.py#L203):

```
    pos_t = torch.tensor([
            not candidateInfo_tup.isNodule_bool,
            candidateInfo_tup.isNodule_bool
        ],
        dtype=torch.long,
    )
```

(Why are two values passed in here when one is completely determined by the other?)

and then [this part](https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/blob/d6c0210143daa133bbdeddaffc8993b1e17b5174/p2ch11/model.py#L24):

```
    self.head_linear = nn.Linear(1152, 2)
    self.head_softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
```

How do I do this?

### Guess

I don't want people to think I haven't thought about this at all, so here is my guess:

First part:

```
    age_t = torch.tensor(candidateInfo_tup.age_int, dtype=torch.double)
```

Second part:

```
    self.head_linear = nn.Linear(299520, 1)
    self.head_relu = nn.ReLU()
```

I'm also guessing that I need to change [this](https://github.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/blob/d6c0210143daa133bbdeddaffc8993b1e17b5174/p2ch11/training.py#L233):

```
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
```

to something like this:

```
    loss_func = nn.L1Loss()
```

My guesses are based on [this article](https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/how-to-create-a-neural-network-for-regression-with-pytorch.md) by [Christian Versloot](https://github.com/christianversloot).

Comment: Quick question, are you sure what you are looking for is regression? If the variable you want to predict is an integer with 35 patterns ranged from 0 to 34, it is called "multiclass classification", not regression. I was curious because your code had `age_int` in it.

Comment: I did think about that.  I decided that regression made more sense.  The number is proportional to the progression of a disease which is gradual, rather than, say, episodic.   Radiologists look at 34 parts of a brain and report 0 or 1 depending on the absence or presence of a lesion.  So that's how you get the int from 0 to 34.  But an individual lesion may vary in severity.  To simplify things, the doctor only needs to report a 0 or 1.  I may end up rounding it off to an int, but I think it really is a regression.

Comment: I see. This is not an answer either, but the example you just described is a "multi-label regression" that predicts 34 variables that range from 0 to 1, instead of 1 variable that ranges from 0 to 34. A multi-label is a bit complicated, so I don't think you need to get into it right now. However, with a multi-label, you might achieve higher accuracy, and you will be able to measure the accuracy per lesion, which will greatly help you to further improvements.

Answer (score 1):

The example from the book is working but it has some redundant elements which confuse you.
Normally output size of 1 is enough for a binary classification problem. To bring it  to 0 or 1, one may use sigmoid and then rounding, like in the example here: [PyTorch Binary Classification - same network structure, 'simpler' data, but worse performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161576/pytorch-binary-classification-same-network-structure-simpler-data-but-wors)
Or just put after single output neuron this:

```
y_pred_binary = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(y_pred))
```

The book example uses output size of 2 and then applies softmax to get to 0 and 1. This works, but such technique is typically used in multi-class classification.

For prediction of 0-34 variable:

- if these are discrete variables - it is called "multiclass classification" as Ken indicated. Use size 35 output and softmax in this case. Search for "pytorch multiclass classification" for examples.
- if this is a regression - than your changes seem in the right direction, except 'Second part'. instead of RELU - clip output at both ends at [0, 34]. Also 299520 - is too much for the previous layer. Use whatever input size there was before. Search for "pytorch regression" for examples.